# Prevent AngularJS interceptor to add token on certain url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps, interceptor

In an AngularJS/Node app, i'm using interceptors to inject an authentification token in my http requests :

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken){

var interceptorFactory = {};
//
// Méthode pour propager le token d'identification dans les headers des pages web
//
interceptorFactory.request = function(config){
    var token = AuthToken.getToken();
    if (token){
        config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
    }
    return config;
};
//
// Méthode pour empécher la navigation si pas de token
//
interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response){
    if (response.status == 403){
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
};

return interceptorFactory;
});
```

However, this mechanism prevents my google api geocode request from functionning, as I receive the following response :

Multi origin request blocked (Cross-Origin Request) : the « Same Origin » policy doesnt allow to receive the distant ressource on  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=.  Reason : « x-access-token » token missing in the CORS header « Access-Control-Allow-Headers »

So, I'm trying to prevent my interceptor to inject the x-access-token if my http request leaves my site, but I cant get the URL I ask to test it.

The idea would be to be able to test what URL will be called in the http request, and if not on my server, not to add the x-access-token.

I tried to add $http after AuthToken in my function parameters but I get a "circular error".

Anybody knows how to circumvent this problem ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: you could parse the url in the config passed into the your request function to check if the domain is the same as the domain in your current location, and add the token as required

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, thing is if logged the config variable passed and couldn't find a URL inside... Am I missing something ?

Comment: I take it back there is indeed a url variable in the config data... I'll try that !

Comment: That did the trick indeedn thx OCA Designs ;)

Comment: no problem, glad I could help